# Why credentials are null when erase_credentials is false?

Tags: symfony

Symfony 5.3

security.yaml

```
security:
    ...
    erase_credentials: false
```

LoginListener.php

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\PasswordHasherFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

class LoginListener
{
    private $passwordHasherFactory;
    private $em;

    public function __construct(PasswordHasherFactoryInterface $passwordHasherFactory, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->passwordHasherFactory = $passwordHasherFactory;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        $token = $event->getAuthenticationToken();

        // Migrate the user to the new hashing algorithm if is using the legacy one
        if ($user->hasLegacyPassword()) {
            // Credentials can be retrieved thanks to the false value of
            // the erase_credentials parameter in security.yml
            $plainPassword = $token->getCredentials();
            file_put_contents('darius.txt', 'test'.$plainPassword, FILE_APPEND); // why null?

        }

        $token->eraseCredentials();
    }
}
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#erase-credentials

> If true, the eraseCredentials() method of the user object is called
> after authentication.

So probably if false it should not erase? Why it is erasing?
Password is received because login works. I just dissapears at some point.

**Update**

Question is why credentials are null before calling

```
$token->eraseCredentials();
```

Comment: You are calling eraseCredentials yourself in your LoginListener. Is that intended?

Comment: I was confused about that as well, but I think the question is why `$plainPassword` is `null`. That's before `eraseCredentials()`.

Comment: @dbrumann - but it is after file_put_contents call, so there still should be the password

Answer (score 0):

Managed to install xdebug and found that when creating token the credentials are not set:

JsonLoginAuthenticator:

```
public function createAuthenticatedToken(PassportInterface $passport, string $firewallName): TokenInterface
    {
        return new UsernamePasswordToken($passport->getUser(), null, $firewallName, $passport->getUser()->getRoles());
    }
```

UsernamePasswordToken:

```
public function __construct($user, $credentials, string $firewallName, array $roles = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($roles);

        if ('' === $firewallName) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('$firewallName must not be empty.');
        }

        $this->setUser($user);
        $this->credentials = $credentials;
        $this->firewallName = $firewallName;

        parent::setAuthenticated(\count($roles) > 0);
    }
```

So I guess that is the problem - under security - firewall there is such setup:

```
main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        logout:
            path: logout
            target: after_logout
        json_login:
            check_path: /login
        entry_point: App\Security\AuthenticationEntryPoint
```

So probably I have answered my question why there is no credentials. I am just missing now how do create new password hash for password on login, but that is probably for different question.